# Adding database to Spring Security and Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

So i followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

But i have trouble figuring out how to add the database.

I have added this to the properties files so i have connection to the database

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

in sql i create a table as follow

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`users` (
  `idusers` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `password` VARCHAR(256) NULL COMMENT '',
  `authority` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusers`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and added some users.

I want this to replace this with the database.

```
@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN", "READER", "WRITER")
            .and()
            .withUser("audit").password("audit").roles("USER", "ADMIN", "READER");
}
```

And something i'm confused of is of that i still need the Principal user when using my own database.

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal user) {

    System.out.println(user.getName());
    System.out.println(user.toString());

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc)
and see how you'll need to change your `globalUserDetails` method to use a `jdbcAuthentication` instead of an `inMemoryAuthentication` :

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

The actual configuration is suited for in memory database as it creates a new schema upon initialisation. In your case you should change it to something like :

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(/* set a query to suit your model*/)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(/* set a query to suit your model*/)
            .groupAuthoritiesByUsername(/* set a query to suit your model*/);
}
```

`Principal` is just an interface that gives you access to the currently logged in user, no more no less.

More on Spring MVC + Security here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal